# Stop the function when the folder doesn't have xlsx files in (Google App scripts)

Tags: google-apps-script, while-loop, xlsx

I have the next function on Google App Script:

```
function remove(){
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('folderID');
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByType(MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL);
  while (files.hasNext()){
    var file = files.next();
    folder.removeFile(file);
  }
}
```

I want stop/break/exit the function when the folder does not have/contains xlsx files.
How I do that?
Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function should work fine. Including stopping if there are no more excel files.

But you do need to change this:

```
   var files = DriveApp.getFilesByType(MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL);
```

(this searches the entire Drive)

to

```
   var files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL);
```

Comment: Excellent! this time the script stop. With my line it does not stop processing ever. Thank you so much @ADW

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
     function remove(){
     var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(''folder's id'');
     var files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL);;
     while (files.hasNext()){
     var file = files.next();
     folder.removeFile(file);

     }
```